# Lambda Timeout Duration not getting updated when updtaes in cdk

Tags: c#, asp.net, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a lambda which is deployed via cdk. When deploying the stack initially, the Lambda time out set to 15 seconds. But later we decided to change it to 300 seconds. So I updated the Duration to 300 and redeployed the stack. But Lambda configuration didn't get updated and is still showing 15 seconds.

```
Function lambda = new Function(this,
            functionId,
            new FunctionProps
            {
                FunctionName = functionName,
                Description = functionDescription,
                Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_6,
                Code = Code.FromAsset(functionPath),
                Handler = functionHandler,
                Environment = envVar,
                Role = role,
                Timeout = Duration.Seconds(300)
            });
```

Comment: Did you refresh the browser? Did you confirm in CloudFormation that the Update was completed?

Comment: @Maurice yes, I did. Also when I checked cdk diff, it didn't bring this duration update, that is bit strange.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example - the cause of the issue is not in the code currently in the question.

Comment: @gshpychka this is the code block I have for Lambda, all I did is changed the line Timeout = Duration.Seconds(15) to Timeout = Duration.Seconds(300). It is not throwing any error ,  the only issue is it didn't update the configuration to 300 seconds. But if I delete the stack and redeploy, it create the lambda with 300 seconds.

Comment: I'm saying the cause of this behavior is not in the code you posted. Can you isolate this to a stack and post the full CDK app that we could synth ourselves and test?